# Circlular number picker but equal distance

Tags: javascript, math

I am currently trying to develop a circular number picker (thus it can be scrolled infinitely), but am running into problems displaying the visible numbers with equal distances.

What I want to achieve is something like this:

[image: Circular picket]

This can be scrolled infinitely (the 10 is right beside the 0).

My current implementation looks like this:

First I calculated the radius and the number of degrees needed for each element in the picker.

```
this._theta = 360 / _this.getPanels().length;
this._radius = Math.round((_this._panelWidth * _this.getPanels().length) / (2 * Math.PI));
```

Then it gets initially rotated to set up the elements in the right order (this method will also be used to rotate the picker):

```
_rotate: function(rotation) {
  this._curRotation = rotation;

  var panels = this._element.children;

  for (var i = 0; i < panels.length; i++) {
    var styleProp = panels[i].style;

    ang = (this._theta * i + 90 + rotation);

    vis = Math.sin(this._toRadians(ang)) >= 0.0;

    styleProp.visibility = vis ? 'visible' : 'hidden';

    if(vis) {
        cos = -Math.cos(this._toRadians(ang));

        styleProp[this._transformProperty] = "translateX("
        + (cos * this._radius) + "px) scale("+ (1 - Math.abs(cos) * 0.333) +")";
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see I calculated the Sine of the angle that each element sits at after the rotation to be able to determine which elements are visible and which are not (I only set the upper semi-circle to be visible). After that I needed to determine the position of each element. Currently I use the Cosine to be able to have equal number of elements to the left and right of the "middle" element.

Now this does work reasonably well for a larger amount of elements (because the radius will be large), but doesn't look that good for fewer ones (this is rotated by 50 degrees!):

[image: Cosine distances]

What I really want is to have equal distance between each visible element, while still maintaining the circular setup. I just cannot figure out how to do this.
Can someone point me into the right direction?

Thank you!

Comment: This is interesting. Even though you describe it as circular, it looks like you are displaying the visible elements on one line (I don't see any transformY). Is that right? Then the results are as expected.  Look at a clock. Imagine you pushed the 9, 10, 11, 1, 2, 3 up to the top row. The 9 and 10 would be much closer together than the 11 and 12.

Comment: Yes the result is as excepted when looking at it as circular (without transformY). I was hoping to keep the circular structure internally (to determine which elements are visible and on what side), while still maintaining equal distance between the elements (thus displaying them on a line) - Working with transformY does look better and is actually something i could live with. Just was wondering if there was a "better" way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One workaround would be to have each element appear twice, or even three times. That would increase the number of elements to the point where the problem would not be as bothersome.